# Storing data of 2 keys and one value using openpyxl and formatting data using PIL on background image

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, openpyxl

I would like to use openpyxl to grab data from cells B2:F6. My headers are in the first row which are Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, ..... While my Column A rows' consist of organizations so something like: finance, hr, marketing. I've stored this data as depicted here on 3 lists and created a dictionary out of it.

```
A2=sheet['A2']          #ROW NAMES
A3=sheet['A3']
A4=sheet['A4']
A5=sheet['A5']              
A6=sheet['A6']          # ROW NAMES



B1=sheet['B1']          # Header NAMES
C1=sheet['C1']
D1=sheet['D1']
E1=sheet['E1']
F1=sheet['F1']          # HEADER NAMES



B2=sheet['B2']          #DATA CELLS
C2=sheet['C2']
D2=sheet['D2']
E2=sheet['E2']
F2=sheet['F2']
B3=sheet['B3']
C3=sheet['C3']
D3=sheet['D3']
E3=sheet['E3']
F3=sheet['F3']
B4=sheet['B4']
C4=sheet['C4']
D4=sheet['D4']
E4=sheet['E4']
F4=sheet['F4']
B5=sheet['B5']
C5=sheet['C5']
D5=sheet['D5']
E5=sheet['E5']
F5=sheet['F5']
B6=sheet['B6']                                                                          #this method of listing is very messy. find other alternative
C6=sheet['C6']
D6=sheet['D6']          
E6=sheet['E6']
F6=sheet['F6']          #DATA CELLS

#----------------------------------------#

                #Lists and Dictionary
rowlist = [A2,A3,A4,A5,A6]
rows = {r: r.value for r in rowlist if r.value is not None}
headerlist = [B1,C1,D1,E1,F1]

datalist = [B2,C2,D2,E2,F2,B3,C3,D3,E3,F3,B4,C4,D4,E4,F4,B5,C5,D5,E5,F5,B6,C6,D6,E6,F6]

dictlist={key : key.value for key in datalist if key.value is not None}
```

Once contents of the sheet are grabbed they are pasted on a background image using PIL. While the data cells are pasted on top of a image that is then pasted onto the background image. 
As of right now I've got working code however my (x,y) at which my data cell images need to be pasted, aren't at the correct coordinates. I could go ahead and create if-then statements however I feel this would limit the script in only being able to correctly execute for a certain amount of rows. If there were to be additional changes it will be unable to do so.

I'd appreciate some advice in which direction to push towards. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, aliasing the cells with variables like `A2=sheet['A2']` seems utterly pointless. And, as you say, will "limit the script in only being able to correctly execute for a certain amount of rows".

`sheet` is already indexable, so why not just use this later in your code?

Secondly, you posted none of the actual problematic code. I suppose the coordinates you are talking about are for the image, how are these calculated?